# Invoke AWS lambda from react application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios

I've developed an AWS function with .net core, it's been deployed to AWS and I can call it from Postman and seems everything's ok, but when I try to call it from a react application with Axios library I get this error:

(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://awsfunctionurl/api/Organisations' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

here is the code to call the API:

```
const response: Response = await axios.get(url,{
      headers:{
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${accesToken}`
      },
    })
```

When I remove Authorization header it starts working!

Comment: As far as I know,`CORS` is caused by Browsers.

Comment: Better look in the CORS settings of your lambda/api gatway, postman simply seem to not enforce them, while the browser where react runs in, of course does

Comment: is it because I'm running this app on my local machine? so if I publish it somewhere should it be working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the request from a local browser, it will block the pre-flight request by default. There are workarounds for this, depending on the browser. [See here, for example, for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome).

Alternatively, it may be easier to just add '"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"' in your response headers from the lambda function itself.

Comment: PS: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" ` Do allow all clients (origins) to request your lambda. Be careful when setting it in production, you need to specifi the origin domain like so.com or urAwesomeSite.org